# chat server implement with message broker

Tags: apache-kafka, server, chat, message

I am trying to implement a chat server using a message broker. Each client is subscribed to a topic unique to itself. For example, user1 is subscribed to chat.dm.user1 and user2 is subscribed to chat.dm.user2. In the chat server, when user1 receives a message from chat.dm.user1, it should forward it to user1's websocket. So, should this be an async task? What I'm afraid of is that if 10,000 clients connect, an async task is created that subscribes to 10,000 topics and delivers messages. Is this common? Or is there any other better way?

eg.

```rust
user1 connected 

async.spawn({
    while let Some(message) = broker.sub("chat.dm.user1") {
        user1'socket.send(message)
    }
})
```